# Got error when trying to get data from client machine which is on Virtual box using tcp from server machine in which wcf is hosted onwindows service

Tags: wcf, tcp, ip, windows-services, client

Got error when trying to get data from client machine which is on Virtual box using tcp from server machine in server machine wcf is hosted on windows service.
Got error when trying to get data from client machine which is on Virtual box using tcp from server machine in which wcf is hosted on windows service.

WCF Service config file code:wcf file is hosted on windows service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
       <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="HelloService.HelloService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="HelloService.IHelloService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://192.168.69.184:8733/WindowsServiceHost/HelloService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="False"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/></startup></configuration>
```

windows service config file code: Got error when trying to get data from client machine which is on Virtual box using tcp from server machine in which wcf is hosted on windows service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="HelloService.HelloService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://192.168.69.184:8733/WindowsServiceHost/HelloService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
       
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please list the specific mistakes you have encountered.

Comment: Inner Exception 1:
AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.

Inner Exception 2:
Win32Exception: No credentials are available in the security package
Meanwhile please copy the detailed logs and share

Comment: You are hosting services through IIS ?  if so, please check if Cipher Suites is required by the server.